# Applying lens distortion correction during panorama image stitching

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, image-stitching

I am trying to do a live panorama stitching while using 6 cameras streams (same camera model). Currently I am adapting the stitching_detailed.cpp file from OpenCV according to my needs.

My cameras lenses have a great amount of barrel distortion. Therefore, I calibrated my cameras with the checkboard function provided by OpenCV and got the respective intrinsic parameters and distortion parameters. By applying getOptimalNewCameraMatrix and initUndistortRectifyMap I get an undistorted image which fulfills my needs.

I have read in several sources that image lens correction should benefit image stitching. So far I have used the previously undistorted images as input to stitching_detailed.cpp, and the resulting stitched image looks fine.

**However, my question is if I could somehow include the undistort step in the stitching pipeline.**

[Stitching Pipeline taken from OpenCV documentation [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZ37G.png)]

- I am doing a cylindrical warping of the images in the stitching
  process. My guess is that maybe during this warping I could somehow
  include the undistortion maps calculated beforehand by
  initUndistortRectifyMap.
- I also do not know if the camera intrinsic matrix K from
  getOptimalNewCameraMatrix could somehow help me in the whole process.

I am kind of lost and any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you want to solve by integrating the distortion correction into the stitcher?

Comment: @Micka as pointed out in the following presentation (http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~fliu/courses/cs510/lectures/Lecture10.pdf) (slide 10) "It is required to do radial distortion correction for better stitching results". 

I believe that it could improve the quality of my stitching results.

Comment: but if I understood your posting right, you already did distortion correction to your images before processing the sitching-pipeline?

Comment: @Micka yes that is right. I did it already. My question is basically if it was correct to do it before executing the stitching algorithm or should I integrate it somewhere in the stitching pipeline? The slides I am using as reference do not provide any details about it.

Comment: doing it before stitching is basically ok. Depending on the actual distortion there could be some problems (how to handle bigger black regions at the image borders? will image quality decrease? etc.) but you would have to invent your own integration that fixes exactly these problems (research topic?)...

Comment: @Micka ok I see... then it is not so straightforward to integrate it in the pipeline. Besides that, do you think that its okay to plug the precalculated K Matrix from getOptimalNewCameraMatrix into the stitching pipeline ?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry.